# two actions need to be performed in one form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to achieve that when I submit data into my form  then it should perform two things . one its open invoice.php file by opening new tab (which its doing) and second thing for which i am facing issue is that , the original tab (where form is open) should return to home page of the website after successfully submitting data. here is my form code :

```
<form method="POST" action="invoice.php"  target="_blank">

<label>Name</label><input type = "text" name = "name1" >
<label>Age</label><input type = "text" name = "age" >
<label>Gender</label><input type = "text" name = "gender" >
<label>Height</label><input type = "text" name = "height" >
<label>Education</label><input type = "text" name = "edu" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-btm" >
</form>
```

Comment: no,  I wanted to open action file in new tab and at the same time wanted to redirect form tab to desired link

Comment: That is not possible. See the accepted answer. `Once you submit a form all JS execution on the current page stops.` As soon as you set the location, the site is reset. `window.location.href = '/';  window.setTimeout(() => console.log("relocated"), 3000);  return true;` will never see the console.log! Because of that the return won't happen and the submit is cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Javascript for this:

```
<form method="POST" action="invoice.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="return redirectToHomePage();">

<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name1">
<label>Age</label><input type="text" name="age">
<label>Gender</label><input type="text" name="gender">
<label>Height</label><input type="text" name="height">
<label>Education</label><input type="text" name="edu">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success submit_btn invoice-save-btm">

</form>

<script>
function redirectToHomePage() {
    // Assuming your home page is at the root of your domain.
    window.location.href = '/';
    
    // Allow the form to continue submitting
    return true;
}
</script>
```